# Call a .phar executable from inside a web app controller

Tags: php, composer-php, webhooks

I need to run `composer.phar update` from a web controller.

I can run all kinds of regular commands in this way (`ls`, `cp`, etc) but when I invoke the phar file I get empty output.

The code I have looks like this:

```
class Maintenance_Controller
{
    public function do_maintenance()
    {
        echo exec("/usr/bin/env php composer.phar", $out, $ret);
        var_dump($out); // outputs -> array()
        var_dump($ret); // outputs -> int(127)
    }
}
```

`127` indicates a bad path, but I am sure I'm in the right directory.

Also, this works when using a php_cli wrapper, so maybe it has to do with the `www-data` user? `chmod 777` does not help, and I hate to do that anyway.

I have also used `passthru()`, `system()` and the backtic syntax. I am unable to get to the reason this doesn't work. I can't seem to interrogate the stderr or stdout from the `exec()` call beyond the `127` code.

#### Obvious Question:

What am I doing wrong?

#### Better Question:

Is there a better way to interrogate and execute `.phar` files from within a script?

Comment: Is there a reason your using `passthru` instead of `exec`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1763156/215966):

> Value 127 is returned by /bin/sh when the given command is not found within your PATH system variable and it is not a built-in shell command.

Try using `exec('php composer.phar', $out, $ret);` and see if that works. You might also need to use the full path to `php` if its in a non-standard location which you can probably get from `which php`.

---

Im not sure why you are using `passthru` here. I would use `exec` for better handling.
Id use `exec` here instead of `passthru`

```
class Maintenance_Controller
{

    public function do_maintenance()
    {
        exec("composer.phar update", $out, $ret);
        if(!$ret) {
            // handle success
        } else {
           // handle error
        }

    }
}
```

This way you have all the output by line in `$out` as well as the shell return val (0 if ok, > 0 if not). If you wanna get really fancy you can loop over `$out` and scan for the errors and then build and exception to throw.

Comment: yeah exec is a better idea. Updated question to use `exec()`.

Comment: Good suggestion - same issue using "/usr/bin/env php composer.phar update"

Comment: Did you try with the full path to `php` instead of executing through `env`?

Comment: I think you can use `PHP_BINDIR` for the full path. Not sure which versions that covers though.

Comment: Turns out the www-data user has a practically empty `$PATH`, so `PHP_BINDIR` is null. It's a linux problem now, not a php problem.

Comment: Add it to the global `.rc`?