# Unable to correctly interpret return values from system() in c program

Tags: c, linux

OS: linux

I am unable to interpret the output from the following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
```

*******updated code*******

```
 void mount_sys() {
    if (0 != mount("none", "/sys", "sysfs", 0, ""))
 {
           /* handle error */
    }
    }


int 
main()
{

int a,b, err;
FILE *file;
err=putenv("PATH=/bin");
printf("putenv return value =%d\n",err);
mount_sys();
;
  err=system("echo 47 > /sys/class/gpio/export");
  if (err == 0) {
    printf("system called good");
  } else {
    perror("Error");
  }

  err=system("echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio47/direction");

  if (err == 0) {
    printf("system called good");
  } else {
    perror("Error");
  }

  err=system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio47/value");

  if (err == 0) {
    printf("system called good");
  } else {
    perror("Error");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Error: Success
Error: Success
Error: Success
```

If all the system calls were successful I should have got `system called good` messages three times.

But it looks like it is failing. But then why the errors being printed using perror() are `Success ?`

Comment: Why not print out the value of `err` and see what you're actually getting for a return value from `system()`?

Comment: you don't declare the `err` variable?

Comment: Another way to troubleshoot this would be to just type `echo 47 > /sys/class/gpio/export` (and so forth) into the shell and see what happens. You should get the same results doing that as calling `system` with that command.

Comment: Regardless of the implementation problem, using a subprocess for this task is rather silly.  Just write to the sysfs node from your program - it will be much more efficient and have fewer configuration dependencies.

Comment: THanks for your comment, Could you please tell me how can i use sysfs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i updated my question  using sysfs.

Comment: Just open the same nodes you were trying to pipe into as regular files, write to them, and close them.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to handle a call to `system()` shall be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> /* For WEXITSTATUS */

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic. */
  char cmd[] = "mycommand";

  int status = system(cmd);
  if (-1 == status)
  {
    perror("system() failed internally");
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "'%s' returned %d.\n", cmd, WEXITSTATUS(status));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by system() can be one of two things:

the exit status of the shell command, or

-1 (indicating that the fork() system call itself failed)

perror() is only relevant in the second case. As others have suggested, print out the value of `err` instead of just relying on perror().

---- update ---
The return value includes both the exit status of the process (top 8 bits) and the signal # that killed the process (if any, lower 8 bits). 32512 == 127 << 8, so the shell exit code 
was 127.

According to this:
[127 Return code from $?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)

that return code indicates that the command you're trying to run (`echo`) is not in the PATH of your shell

Comment: I did printf("value return=%d\n",err); but the value i am getting is too high 32512, what is this value means?

Comment: And what was the result that was printed?

Comment: the return value, i am getting 32512

Comment: I think my system call is working fine (since the return value is not -1). Also 32512 is the exit status code of my shell command i.e echo. Am I right ?

Comment: To stay portable use `WEXITSTATUS()` on the value returned by `system()` (if >0) to get the programs exit code.