# NodeJS/Dokku/Docker: ffmpeg exited with code 127

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, docker, dokku

I'm trying to run ffmpeg inside of a Docker container via Dokku. I've [heavily modified](https://github.com/mattcodez/dokku-ffmpeg) a Dokku plugin to accomplish this as I need h264 support. I currently get an error from fluent-ffmpeg which states

> Error: ffmpeg exited with code 127

I've tried to look up what error code 127 is but haven't found much. Some people seem to suggest that it's some sort of issue with finding ffmpeg. However, I did have a libx264 error from ffmpeg earlier in the process so I'm pretty sure the ffmpeg binary is being found. Unfortunately fluent doesn't send the used command line for ffmpeg to the error event so I'm not sure what the exact command being ran is.

Answer (score 3):

127 means command not found. ([127 Return code from $?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from))

I guess your `ffmpeg` executable is not located in any directories defined by environment variable `PATH`.