# Nandroid backup failed exitcode[127]

Tags: backup, rom, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I need to create a customized flashable ROM, by customized i mean i will add some apps into it and redistribute this new ROM.
Now, first of all I've read that I could create a flashable ROM through Nandroid backups. but somehow when installed and execute a Clockwork backup it returns just this:

```
Starting backup...
Running with the following commands : -o --utc --storage /sdcard -pd -r
Using default shell
exitcode[127]
```

What's happening? Actually this is not a Smartphone but an Android Head Unit called `Full AOSP on Mstar Cedric3`
I can put zip file to upgrade the firmware instead the official readme suggest that i should extract all zip contents into a micro sd card and the device will update the contents one by one like first CIS, boot, recovery, system, data etc etc

any help?

Answer (score 0):

See [127 Return code from $?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from).
Check if busybox is installed.