# NetBeans C++ will BUILD but not RUN (exit value 127) when I use a "string" command in my code

Tags: c++, string, netbeans, runtime-error, netbeans-8.1

Hey i'm pretty new to coding and I can't seem to get a very basic string program to work. Here is my code:

```
# #include <string> 
# #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
string name;
cin >> name;
string message("hi");
cout << name << message;
return 0;
}
```

This is a very generic example but whenever I run it in NetBeans 8.1 it will build but not run and give me this:

Process is started in an external terminal ...

RUN FAILED (exit value 127, total time: 352ms)

Any other file I run will work as long as it does not contain a string command. I figure it must be something with the settings in NetBeans. I've tried using std:: etc etc but it doesn't fix the problem. Any tips/advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your include statements are wrong. Is that the actual code or a copying error here?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `include` statements to have only one `#` symbol preceding them.

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>
```

This would hopefully fix your error; the rest of the code seems fine.