# Pandoc error - turning HTML document to PDF. Error Code 127

Tags: r, pdf, pandoc

I'm working with code to try to convert html to pdf using pandocs

```
# Load packages
require(knitr)
require(markdown)

# Create .md, .html, and .pdf files
knit("Data Analysis - Quant.Rmd")
markdownToHTML('Data Analysis - Quant.md', 'dat.html', options=c("use_xhml"))
system("pandoc -s dat.html -o dat.pdf")
```

I get the following inexplicable error code:

```
Warning message:
running command 'pandoc -s dat.html -o dat.pdf' had status 127
```

I can't find anything about this warning online, and no pdf output is produced in the working directory.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [127 Return code from $?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)