# rake db:migrate fails in db:structure:dump with no error output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I currently changed my `ActiveRecord` schema format to `:sql` and when migrating (`rake db:migrate`), I get the following error with no real explanation as to what is wrong:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Error dumping database

Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm using **Rails 4.2.4** and **PostgreSQL 9.4**.

Answer (score 1):

After following the debug trail in the Rails code, I finally discovered the error.

The `pg_dump` command is being executed in [activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#54](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L54). After printing the output of the command execution with `$?`, I realized it was returning a 127 exit code, which means that the [command was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from).

It turns out that the `pg_dump` command was not in my executable `PATH`.
I simply added it by creating a symbolic link and it all worked fine:

`ln -s /opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin/pg_dump /usr/local/bin`

**NOTE:** I also found out that the issue of not printing out the error has already been fixed in [Rails 4.2.5](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L90)