# bash: ????: command not found

Tags: bash, macos, shell, executable

(*I'm using bash 3.2 in the Terminal app on OS X 10.11.4.*)

I have this line in my `.bashrc` file: `alias ll='ls -alFh'`

I ran `echo ll > test && chmod +x test` to create a `test` executable. Below are the results of running multiple commands, their exit codes (via `echo $?`), and `stdout`:

1. `test`
   exit code 1
   produces no stdout
2. `./test`
   exit code 127
   produces `./test: line 1: ll: command not found`
3. `. test`
   exit code 127
   produces `-bash: ????: command not found`
4. `. ./test`
   exit code 0
   produces identical result to manually running `ll`

I understand that exit code 1 is a generic error and that exit code 127 means [the shell can't find the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763178/438273). Will someone please explain what is happening in each of these cases and why, including a description of the stdout? I am especially confused at #3 with the `????`.

Comment: @sjsam I perused many links from multiple similar searches already and found nothing pertinent to #3 before posting this question.

Comment: For the record, my path is fine. @sjsam the downvote is not necessary—you obviously did not fully read my question and compare it to any of the results you linked to.

Comment: What happens if - you create the `test`,close the terminal, start a new terminal session and execute the commands in the order you have given?

Comment: @sjsam The results are identical.

Comment: I tried this and couldn't reproduce it.  I don't know where that ???? is coming from for you.

Comment: This happened probably because the current shell session was initiated with an old version of .bashrc . You might add a `shebang` to `test` to resolve case 2 I guess.. You might use `type ll` to check if aliases are in working.

Comment: @sjsam I duplicated the file as `test2` and added `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang and still no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you run:

```
echo ll > test && chmod +x test
```

then these cases.

**Case 3:**

When you execute:

```
. test
```

it is equivalent of:

```
source test
```

`source` is a shell builtin that tells the shell to read the given script file and execute the commands in the **current shell environment**. However since **current path** or `.` is not in your path, it finds `test` using `PATH` environment variable which is `/bin/test`.

`/bin/test` is not really a script file that can be read/executed by `source`; it ends up reading a binary file and errors out since that file is a binary file, not an ascii text file and errors out writing:

```
????: command not found
```

You will get same behavior when you run `source date` or `source ls` as these are all binary files.

**Case 1:**

You are executing shell builtin `test` without any arguments that makes it exits with exit value: `1`

**Case 2:**

When you run `./test` it attempts to run `ll` and `alias` is not available in spawned sub-shell hence it cannot find alias `ll`. Due to that fact it exits with exit value: `127` with `./test: line 1: ll: command not found` error on `stderr`.

**Case 4:**

`. ./test` is same as `source ./test` that run in current shell only. Therefore it  is able to find alias you've set earlier for `ll` hence it runs aliased command `ls -alFh` and exits with `0`

Comment: This partly addresses #3, but it doesn't answer my question: an explanation for each of them. It also doesn't cover the reason for the `????` in the output (for example, vs `-bash: test: command not found`)

Comment: It does explain reason of `???? in the output` (reading **binary** file `/bin/test`)

Comment: When I run another command that doesn't exist, say `marcopolo` for example, I get `-bash: marcopolo: command not found` (exit code 127).

Comment: Yes because `marcopolo` doesn't exist. Try running `source date` or `source ls` to see same behavior.

Comment: I see what you mean with the `????` now. Case 4 DOES succeed, though. In your answer you are saying that it doesn't, but re-read my question.

Comment: Also, why isn't Case 2 a valid executable? I'd like a longer form explanation or links to some documentation. This information is not enough to help me understand what is happening or what problems exist.

Comment: First of all there should be one question per SO thread. I replied but hope you appreciate it. case 2 is not a valid executable because `./test` means **try to run test in current directory**. Finally `. ./test; echo $?` will indeed exit with `1` as my answer says. Your question is not correct on case #4

Comment: I do appreciate your responding, but what you're saying about case 4 is simply not correct—it does succeed and exits with code 0. Are you testing on OS X?

Comment: I don't think your demo is right because it doesn't contain the .bashrc or executable created in the steps leading up to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is starting to make more sense now. I still don't understand the difference between case 3 and 4. Why does it find `/bin/test` in case 3 and not the `test` file I made, and in case 4 why does it find the `test` file I made and not `/bin/test`?

Comment: Actually I wrote the reason of that in my answer. When you run `source test` it won't find `test` file in your current directory because `.` (DOT) is not included in your `PATH` variable hence it finds `/bin/test` since `/bin/` is in the path. Case 4 is different because you're using `./test` which **means run test from current directory** and then it won't even check the PATH

Comment: I understand what is happening, but I don't understand why. Does the path always receive priority over specifying a file in the current directory without a leading path? (ex. `source file` vs `source ./file`) Is this only true with the `source` command or is it true with other commands, too? (ex. `rm file` vs `rm ./file`)

Comment: PATH is not even checked when you invoke it as `./test` (which means run `test` from current directory). Only when you don't provide any path before `test` like `source test` then only path is checked. Please try to spend some time on reading unix paths resolution outside this question.

Comment: Great—that's the kind of information I needed. Thanks!