# An easy way to figure out why a docker container keep restarting

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container which keeps restarting;

```
           Name                         Command                 State                  Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wenotecloudstorage_flask_1   /bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/ ...   Restarting
wenotecloudstorage_nginx_1   nginx -g daemon off;             Up           0.0.0.0:2083->443/tcp, 80/tcp
```

I wish I had an easy way to look at the error log on why it is restarting.

I read on [Docker: Container keeps on restarting again on again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471929/docker-container-keeps-on-restarting-again-on-again)

I try;

```
docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps wenotecloudstorage_flask_1
error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: EOF
```

Is there an easy way that I can figure out the reason why a docker container keeps restarting?

Comment: I would say attach to the docker, that will give you information, and of course checking the logs of the docker.

Comment: Do you mean doing `docker attach wenotecloudstorage_flask_1`? But, that still give me error `You cannot attach to a restarting container, wait until it is running`

Comment: you could stop the container, and they start it without detaching

Comment: Do you mean first run `docker stop wenotecloudstorage_flask_1`, then followed by `docker start --attach wenotecloudstorage_flask_1`? As, after running `docker start --attach wenotecloudstorage_flask_1`, 0 output is shown in console and the container fall back to Restarting.

Comment: The docker daemon log might provide some insight as well. The location varies based on your system, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log

Comment: If the main container process exits immediately (because of a startup configuration error; because you tried to launch a background process) that could in theory cause this; you might try running it without the `-d` option to get live logs.  Seeing the actual `docker-compose.yml` might give some hints.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng also make sure you are not passing the `restart` policy to the containers you run.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use "docker logs". Use "docker-compose logs flask" (flask being the name of the container) to see the logs of that restarting containers.
With your options:

```
docker-compose logs -f --tail=50 flask
```

The error you see is because the normal "docker logs" is trying to read the logs, but the container dies already. Docker-compose handles it better.

If it is not in the logs, well, then you will have to dig deeper in the configuration of your app. But my bet is that you will see a nice log message that will bring you to the right direction.

Comment: what does `flask` stands for?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant "flags", meaning the command options (i.e. -f, --tail, etc) I corrected it.

Comment: And sorry again ... Flask is the name of the container the user posted.

Answer (score 3):

**Ensure The Command Does Not Exit**

Had the same issue, container kept restarting but both `docker logs` and `docker-compose logs` just showed me clean logs in a loop, with no clue about the restarts.

Then I realized that indeed there was no error, it was simply exiting because of the `command` I added to the YML configuration. To verify it, I appended `tail -f /dev/null` to the last command, e.g.:

```
command: bash -c "nginx -t  && tail -f /dev/null"
```

And this time, it stayed up!

**Use The Proper Command**

With the theory confirmed, I looked up the proper `CMD` with `docker inspect $image_id` and used a proper command, e.g.:

```
command: bash -c "nginx -t && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

**Why Does it Restart**

Two possible causes are, there's an error, or the [command exits early](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907131/5362795). In my case, it was the latter. I was previously using an image which already had the correct `CMD` above. But I wanted to add some extra commands without having to use a separate dockerfile.

So I ditched the dockerfile and used [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) since the compose file does not have a `RUN` equivalent (correct me otherwise). However, it "overrides the default command declared by the container image", which was the one preventing the container from exiting early.

**How To Identify The Restart Cause**

Look at the output of `docker ps`, I believe that the number in brackets in e.g. "*Restarting (1)*", is the exit code. You can also run `docker-compose` in the foreground (not detached, i.e. without `-d`) so you can see the logs and potential exit codes in real time.

Or run this command:

```
docker inspect $your_container_name | grep -i state -C 12
```

Look for the State object:

```
"State": {
    "Status": "restarting",
    "Running": true,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": true,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 0,
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "Error": "",
    ...
},
```

The main thing to look for here is the `ExitCode`. If it's 0, and there's no `Error`, chances are that the command finishes early, i.e. it's not running as a service. If the code is not 0, there's an actual execution error and you should be able to see it with `docker-compose logs` or `docker logs`.

Comment: I found this most helpful - it happened to identify the issue that was making my container restart: the `command` line in docker-compose.yml that I was trying to write. 

My fix was slightly different however, which I'll note for any future readers that it may be useful for:

Comment: - I found my original command that was being overwritten with `docker image inspect [image] | grep Cmd -A4`, which was `apache2-forefound`.
- Then I had to put that at the *END* of my line in docker-compose.yml:  `command: sh -c "/myscript.sh; apache2-foreground"`

And I'll add that resources for using `command` in docker-compose were difficult to find online, I assume due to the generic nature of the name. This official reference (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command) doesn't mention anything about there being a command overwritten in the background.