# php use the exec() return 127

Tags: php, linux

I would like to execute a statement on my website, the server environment is LNMP, the single always return 127, can not be executed.

---

```
$dir = 'php /alidata/www/index.php gitblog exportsite';
exec("$dir",$output,$is_success);
print_r($output);
echo"<br>";
echo $is_success;
echo"<br>";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [127 Return code from $?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)

Answer (score 0):

Error code  `127` is returned for an illegal command.  Try

```
$output=array(); // $output should be an array
$dir = '/alidata/www/index.php gitblog exportsite';
exec("$(which php) $dir",$output,$is_success);
```

Comment: i use your way,and now its return 126,there is nothing in the $output

Comment: @J.Cai : That looks like a permission issue to me. Check [\[ this \]](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html) list to know more..