# Error installing Rtools - devtools::has_devel() fails

Tags: r

I want to create an R package and downloaded Rtools and packages `c("devtools", "roxygen2", "testthat", "knitr")`. Now I check if everything is alright:

`library(devtools)
has_devel()`

and it's not, I get the error:

```
"C:/Users/xxx/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
  --quiet CMD SHLIB foo.c 

Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/Users/XYZ/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/XYZ/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="foo.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="foo.o"' had status 127 
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I use Windows and the freshest RStudio.

Do you know what it means or how to repair it?

Comment: Potentially [relevant SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I made light edits to your text and title to make it a little easier to read.

Comment: what is SO ?   ???

Answer (score 1):

lol I have just ran this code:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/devtools")
devtools::build_github_devtools()
find_rtools()
has_devel()
build_github_devtools()
```

from
https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1219

and now `has_devel` returns TRUE :O :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for you, in a previous time I changed the R executable to run as administrator. (don't do that!) I went to 
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64 and right clicked the R executable. go to compatability mode, deselect run as administrator.

Everything works again.