# Error While Compiling C++ Sources When Building Scikit-Learn for Development

Tags: python, c++, build, scikit-learn, g++

When I am trying to build `scikit-learn` from source via the `python setup.py install` I receive this error:

```
compiling C++ sources
C compiler: g++ -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

compile options: '-I/home/sharan/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c'
g++: sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp

error: Command "g++ -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/sharan/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.o.d" failed with exit status 127
```

**Command failed with exit status 127**

I am building the library on **Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit**.

To add, all the necessary prerequisites are installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-setuptools \
                 python3-numpy python3-scipy \
                 libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base

sudo update-alternatives --set libblas.so.3 \
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3

sudo update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3 \
/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3

sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message, or better, the complete output of python setup.py install.

Comment: [What is the meaning of return value 127 from $? in UNIX.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)