# What does Usage: psql [wait] mean?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to use `psql` version 9.6 on Mac OSX 10.11 and installed from [the EnterpriseDB installer](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) but I'm getting the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:local me$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
MacBook-Pro:local me$ /usr/local/bin/psql -h localhost; echo "Error code: $?"
Usage: /usr/local/bin/psql [wait]
Error code: 127
```

As you can see, I'm simply trying to connect to localhost and I'm getting a usage error despite following the syntax from the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html).

What is happening here?

Comment: Usually in usage statements `[...]` means an optional argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake - `/usr/local/bin/psql` was a symlink for `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/scripts/runpsql.sh` which doesn't accept any arguments... it's basically EnterpriseDB's shell script wrapper around the actual actual binary which is `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql`.

I just needed to point `psql` to the real executable and not that shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Your bash is returning the error code 127: command not found.
See [127 Return code from $?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from) for more details about this bash code.
Make sure that psql is in the directory you're trying to access.

Comment: You can find where your psql bin is by issuing the following command in a terminal: whereis psql or which psql. Both command will return the path where psql is

Comment: Right, I added the status code to give a little more info. There doesn't seem to be a PATH issue or anything. I added two more lines in the original post to be more explicit

Comment: I tried your code on my Mac, and I had to explicit the database I connect to by adding --dbame=DATABASE_NAME (I used postgres as there usually is one named like that)