# Command failed with status (127) when executing Bash script in a Rakefile on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, bash, sh, rake

**Say I have the following bash script...**

*bin/my-script.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello world!"
```

**And the following Rakefile...**

```
namespace :dev do
    desc "Execute my- scripts"
    task :done do
        sh "bin/my-script.sh"
    end 
end
```

**And I'm running** `rake dev:done` **through** `cmd` **in the root directory..**

**Why do I receive the following error?**

```
> rake dev:done
bin/my-script.sh
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [bin/my-script.sh...]
```

Comment: what happens when you run the script in the command line?

Comment: Exit code 127 means [the command was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from). It can also be caused if `my-script.sh` does not have execution capabilities. Try running `chmod +x my-script.sh`.