# Markdown preview in emacs fails: (pandoc?) error 127

Tags: emacs, markdown, pandoc, preview

I am trying to create a markdown document in Emacs *.

It does highlight the syntax etc. and goes into Markdown mode (I am not quite sure if I installed that package or if it is standard issue)..

#### Problem:

When I try to create a preview (either via `C-c C-c p` or the GUI), it returns this error code:

> markdown failed with exit code 127

#### Question

- What does this error tell me? Is there a way to get a more complete error message?
- The [docs](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) for markdown-mode suggest that it calls on an external library such as pandoc, which I have installed. According to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandoc+error+127) SO questions, pandoc can return this error code, but I could not quite establish what it means.
- How do I fix this / what documentation should I go to?

I am pretty new to Emacs, so anything will help. Thanks!

*Emacs version 25.3.1 on a Mac (Sierra 10.12.6)

Comment: Pandoc doesn't use error code 127. My [guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from) is that emacs cannot find a `markdown` program. You might have to symlink to pandoc (or configure emacs, e.g. by running <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(setq markdown-command "/usr/bin/pandoc")`) to make it work.

Comment: thank you sir, that solved all my problems. Much appreciated. As explained in the link, 127 is a general shell error code that the function was not found.

Comment: Just first make sure you have `pandoc` installed and if not, install it.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest fix is likely to install the `markdown` package using your package manager.

I fixed this error for myself with:

`$ brew install markdown`

(on MacOS Mojave, at the bash command line).  Brew installed the "bottle" `markdown-1.0.1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz`, after which `C-c C-c p` or `M-x markdown-preview` worked to export the markdown file and open a browser window showing the exported file.

On an Ubuntu 19 (and now 20.04 and 21.10) system, `sudo apt install markdown` worked too.

You could do the same thing with a symlink to pandoc's markdown, but a) this just worked, b) there's no fiddling with a potentially messed up manually created symlink, and c) it's tiny (a 36 KByte executable).  Pandoc's markdown may support more "modern" markdown, though.

Comment: For Ubuntu user, it would be `sudo apt install markdown`. Once `markdown` package was installed, the preview started working for me