# Extracting sound from videos using subprocess and ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract a .wav file from a .mp4 file using the following code:

```
import subprocess
import ffmpeg

command = "ffmpeg -i afoomtx.mp4 -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn audio.wav"

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

The only output I get is `127`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `127` means "command not found" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from. You may want to try using absolute path such as `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [127 Return code from $?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)

Comment: import ffmpeg is not required in your script. Ensure ffmpeg installed in your machine and your python script and afoomtx.mp4 file are under the same folder.

Comment: Note that wav is uncompressed so it ignores `-ab`.