# Setting up java for VS Code on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ide, output

heads up I am new here, so please have mercy and take it easy on me.

so I recently moved to Ubuntu and am having trouble setting up VS Code. For the pass few years I have been getting away with using repl .it, so I never had to set up an IDE before, much less in a Linux distro

I've installed the following extensions and my jdk;
Code Runner,
Debugger for Java,
Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat, and
[Image of open jdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYq51.png)

I thought all I needed was to install these extensions and open jdk, but when I tried to run a hello world in java I receive the following output

[Running] cd "/home/santiago/" && javac hello.java && java hello
/bin/sh: 1: javac: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.011 seconds

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code=127 means:
the given command is not found within your PATH system variable and it is not a built-in shell command. In other words, the system doesn't understand your command, because it doesn't know where to find the binary you're trying to call. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)

So, it seems like you hadn't setted the JAVA_HOME Path. and this page can give you a little help:https://vitux.com/how-to-setup-java_home-path-in-ubuntu/