# Azure Devops build a docker image for asp.net with react

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I am creating the azure devops pipeline to build an asp.net web app with react and then create a Docker image. I use below azure-pipeline.yml, and docker file, but I have issue on npm package.
Can anybody support me how can I create it:
Docker file to restore, build, push and create image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./react.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./react.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "react.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "react.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "react.dll"]
```

azure pipeline to create an image and push it to azure container registry.

```
pool:
  name: Default

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Build services'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
    azureContainerRegistry: '$(Parameters.azureContainerRegistry)'
    dockerComposeFile: '$(Parameters.dockerComposeFile)'
    dockerComposeFileArgs: 'DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE='
    action: 'Build services'
    additionalImageTags: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    includeLatestTag: true

- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Push services'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
    azureContainerRegistry: '$(Parameters.azureContainerRegistry)'
    dockerComposeFile: '$(Parameters.dockerComposeFile)'
    additionalDockerComposeFiles: 'docker-compose.ci.yml'
    dockerComposeFileArgs: 'DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE='
    action: 'Push services'
    additionalImageTags: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    includeLatestTag: true

- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Lock services'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
    azureContainerRegistry: '$(Parameters.azureContainerRegistry)'
    dockerComposeFile: '$(Parameters.dockerComposeFile)'
    additionalDockerComposeFiles: 'docker-compose.ci.yml'
    dockerComposeFileArgs: 'DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE='
    action: 'Lock services'
    outputDockerComposeFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/docker-compose.yml'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    Contents: |
     **/docker-compose.env.yml
     **/docker-compose.env.*.yml
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: docker-compose'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: 'docker-compose'
```

You may find the react.csproj here:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  react -> /src/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/react.dll
  my-new-app -> /src/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/react.Views.dll
  /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmp0521ff029b114917be8a23c5908b7043.exec.cmd: npm: not found
/src/react.csproj(36,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 127.
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish "my-new-app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Can you show what you have in this line ` /src/react.csproj(36,5):`?

Comment: Yes, it is added above.

Comment: Please check if below answer helps to resolve your issue. Feel free to let me know if it's helpful or not~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Description of code 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from).

The error `MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 127` indicates that `npm install` command is not recognized by the system since it's not defined in `PATH` variable or located in current working directory.

Your image contains `dotnet sdk` while it doesn't have `npm` installed so it's expected behavior to get such error.

**Workaround:**

Modify your `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./react.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./react.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "react.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "react.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "react.dll"]
```

You should choose the correct `node.js` version for your project. For example, change the `setup_12.x`(Line5 and Line9) to `setup_10.x`  if `node.js` version `10.x` is more suitable for you.

More details about that you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2019#modify-the-dockerfile-linux-containers).

Comment: Thanks man! it works :) and in your opinion, is this way logical and correct?