# docker compose in ado pipeline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get docker-compose to run in the Azure Dev Ops pipeline with my yaml file but I keep getting errors like the following

```
Using docker-compose from 'dockerComposePath' 
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 1: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: version:: not found
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 2: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: services:: not found
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 3: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: app1:: not found
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 4: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: build:: not found
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 5: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: context:: not found
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 6: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: app2:: not found
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 8: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: build:: not found
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 9: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: ports:: not found
##[error]/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: 10: /agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml: -: not found
##[error]The process '/agent/_work/6/s/docker-compose.yml' failed with exit code 127
```

My docker-compose.yml is the following

```
  - task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: 'Start docker compose'
    inputs:
      containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
      dockerComposePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/docker-compose.yml'
      dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'
      action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
      dockerComposeCommand: 'up -d'
```

I originally thought it had to do with CRLF vs LF but changing those didn't affect anything. This builds locally fine with the "docker compose up" command.

my docker-compose.yml is the following

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build: 
      context: ./test/app1
  app2:
    build: ./test/app2
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

note: I have also tried this in the yaml file but similar errors.

```
  #- task: DockerCompose@0
  #  displayName: docker compose - Build services
  #  inputs:
  #    action: Build services
  #    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: <redacted>
  #    azureContainerRegistry: <redacted>
  #    containerregistrytype: Azure Container Registry
  #    dockerComposePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/docker-compose.yml'
  #    #dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
  #    projectName: aakriti-test
  #    qualifyImageNames: true
  #    additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
  #    dockerComposeFileArgs: |
  #      firstArg=$(firstArg)
  #      secondArg=$(secondArg)
```

Answer (score 1):

The 127 is related to [not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from).

Might be related to your `dockerComposePath`? I'm not sure if you need to provide the `/s` after the `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`.

```yaml
  - task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: 'Start docker compose'
    inputs:
      containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
      #dockerComposePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/docker-compose.yml' If you remove the path the current work directory will be used
      dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'
      action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
      dockerComposeCommand: 'up -d'
```

If it doesn't work, I would try a PowerShell task just be sure that everything is ok with the `CRLF` like you said, something like:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Docker compose'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'docker-compose up -d'
```

Comment: If I do not have the /s in the compose path I get a " Unable to locate executable file: 'docker-compose.yml'", so I know the file is being reached.

Comment: powershell output:
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/agent/_work/_temp/ec89e170-0872-40d8-ab6d-5fac701f584a.ps1'
docker-compose: /agent/_work/_temp/ec89e170-0872-40d8-ab6d-5fac701f584a.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  docker-compose up -d
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'docker-compose' is not recognized as a name of a
     | cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check
     | the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
     | that the path is correct and try again.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Comment: might be possible that your agent does not have the `docker-compose` installed?

Comment: thanks @lucas . After installing docker compose into my agent with "sudo apt install -y docker-compose" the powershell that has docker-compose task ran fine. However, the dockercompose task still gives the errors as mentioned above

Comment: Are you getting the same error when running your pipeline on a Microsoft hosted agent?